# Angular 2 Consuming JSON

Tags: html, json, angular

I am learning angular 2 and looking for a code which can help in consuming JSON and showing that on UI. Please pass me a piece of code which i can use to consume JSON and show it on UI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code. Show us the json file you want to display. o you receive the json file from a service call or is it already in local?

Comment: just follow The Hero tutorial on the angular website, that will guide you the best.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to show object of your array like...

TypeScript:

```
new1 = any[] = [{name:'Name1'},{name:'Name2'}];
```

Then you should be use in angular 2 using *ngFor

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let employee of new1">{{employee.name}}</li></ul>
```

You get result like that

Name1

Name2